# Can you save and insert SQL Query Messages in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a feeling this is an extremely newbie question, but it's hard to find the answer as anything to do with logging points me to SQL errors and issues. If not that, then the answer is querying the entire log to sift through.

When I insert data into an existing table via TSQL. How can I save or reference the Query Message for that specific statement? That way I can take the Query Message and insert the result into a log table that specifies how many records got inserted, maybe a duration of time it took and etc.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and these SQL statements are stored procedures inserting data and updating data. I want to ensure every step of the process is logged and inserted into a specific log table with details about that step of the process.

Thanks for your help on this (I'm assuming) newbie question. I'm still learning MSSQL.

Comment: By _Query Message_ do you mean something like "(1 row(s) affected)" as displayed by SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?

Comment: You can issue `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;` immediately after the query.

Comment: Correct. I've attached this to an email with a query once that showed rows inserted along with query time. I assume you can do the same by inserting the log at runtime too?

Comment: Do any of the stored procedures use PRINT to output messages you want to capture?

Comment: None use PRINT, but that's what I was aiming for. To print out the query message output in order to insert into a record. Aaron gave a good suggestion below that aims to please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME2(7), @duration INT, @rowcount INT;

SET @dt = SYSDATETIME();

INSERT dbo.foo(bar) VALUES('x');

SELECT @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT, @duration = DATEDIFF(MICROSECOND, @dt, SYSDATETIME());

INSERT dbo.LoggingTable(duration,row_count) SELECT @duration, @rowcount;
```

In 2005 or lower, you can't get quite that precise, e.g.

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME, ...

SET @dt = GETDATE();

...

... , @duration = DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @dt, GETDATE());
```

Comment: Thanks. Does @@ROWCOUNT or ROWCOUNT_BIG() have any performance issues as I assume these check the table after the query as opposed to at runtime of query?

Comment: And there is no way to show query time (i.e.: how long it took query to run) as well?

Comment: There is no performance impact of using @@ROWCOUNT that I know of, and if there is, it is absolutely negligible. SQL Server has to keep track of the number of rows affected, whether you ask for it afterward or not. It absolutely does not query the table to get this information.

Comment: Also, neat trick on the GETDATE and DATEDIFF calls. Simple, easy and effective :)

Comment: @Fastidious - Note that resolution of SYSDATETIME() depends on the underlying operating system and may not extend to microseconds. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630353(v=sql.100).aspx). _(It's not just good, it's good enough!)_

Comment: @HABO while true, I doubt that any variances in accuracy due to the underlying OS will be any cause for concern (we're talking about microseconds, after all). I also don't think that the documentation states or even implies that the function call will be unable to draw milliseconds at all - my interpretation is that they may be slightly off, rounded, etc., not just discarded.

Comment: One might assume that you have suggested that resolution in microseconds is available in versions of SQL Server after 2005. One might be correct, but one might choose to verify the result on their particular system. SQL Server 2008R2 appears to be returning values that increment by 1,000,000ns on my notebook. DATETIME accuracy is "Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds", thus making millisecond resolution unavailable on earlier versions of SQL Server.

Comment: @Avarkx one does not simply walk into datetime resolution

Comment: @HABO: Please look up (and understand) the difference in precision between datetime and datetime2 values (the latter being introduced in SQL Server 2008).  Datetime2 is accurate to 100ns and datetime is accurate to 3 1/3ms.  The OP never states that she/he needs greater precision than any of these data types, so the point is moot.

Comment: @tommy_o - Sorry you misunderstood my point. GETDATE() does not return values accurate to the millisecond and SYSDATETIME() accuracy is specified as the value returned by the GETSYSTEMTIMEADJUSTMENT API. It's lovely that a DATETIME2 can _represent_ time down to a [clunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS#Timekeeping). That doesn't mean that any particular data source, e.g. a sundial or SYSDATETIME(), will provide it. Give AB's answer another casual read and see if you think it implies millisecond (GETDATE) or microsecond (SYSDATETIME) resolution is available.

Comment: @HABO I don't understand all the nit-picking. The OP asked how to get the row count and duration of his queries. I offered a solution with as much precision as is possible in current versions of SQL Server. I only offered a 2005 version because initially I didn't know what version the user was on. So instead of complaining about my answer, why don't you tell everyone what unit of time you would use, if you had bothered to answer?

Comment: Crikey! My original comment did not say the answer was **WRONG**!!! and it was directed at the OP, not The AB. It suggested that the resolution of the results should not be taken at face value without further inspection. My thought was to prevent future readers from glancing at the answer and assuming that microsecond timing resolution is available. I'm sorry I've burdened the SO community with two questions and 357 answers.  _The end._

Comment: Interesting discussion that I have spawned. Thanks for the input (all of you)! I developed a robust log system from your help. :)